# Why doesn't traversing linked list in javascript alter the list?

Tags: javascript, object, linked-list, closures

```
const LinkedListFactory = () => {
    let _list = {head: null, tail: null};

    const append = (value) => {
        const node = NodeFactory(value);
        if (!_list.head) {
            _list.head = node;
            _list.tail = node;
        } else {
            _list.tail.next = node;
            _list.tail.next.prev = _list.tail;
            _list.tail = _list.tail.next;
        }
        updateDisplay();
    }

    const prepend = (value) => {
        const node = NodeFactory(value);
        if (!_list.head) {
            _list.head = node;
            _list.tail = node;
        } else {
            _list.head = {value: node.value, next: _list.head, prev: null}
            _list.head.next.prev = _list.head;
        }
        updateDisplay();
    }

    const size = () => {
        if (!_list.head) return 0;
        let count = 1;
        let current = _list.head;
        while (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    const insertAt = (value, index) => {
        if (index < 0) return 'invalid input: negative index';
        if (index === 0) return prepend(value);
        if (index >= size() || !_list.head) return append(value); //if index > list size OR list is empty, then append the value

        let current = _list.head;
        while (index > 0) {
            current = current.next; //(*)
            index--;
        }
        current = {value: value, next: current, prev: current.prev}; //(**)
        current.prev.next = current; //(**)
        current.next.prev = current; //(**)

        updateDisplay();
    }

    return {
        append, prepend, insertAt, _list //only for testing purposes
    }
}

let list = LinkedListFactory();
list.append(1);
list.append(2);
list.prepend(0);
console.log(list._list);
```

Above is a method for a linked list that contains a head/tail property, and each node contains prev/value/next properties. The question lies in traversing the linked list, this is merely an example I wrote that works 100% correctly, I just don't know why it works.

On the lines marked with (**) the actual linked list (_list, a private object in a closure) is mutated. But the linked marked with (*) merely traverses the list but does not mutate _list at all. Why is that the case? I'm setting the current node equal to the following node, shouldn't that delete the current node altogether?

Again, this works as intended, but looking back at my old code I got more confused. I would greatly appreciate any clarification or direction in concepts to look into.

Comment: Why do you think that `current = current.next;` should alter the list? The variable `current` is a local variable.

Comment: Assigning a variable has no effect on the object that the variable points to.

Comment: A variable isn't a macro that gets replaced with the original expression. After doing `current = _list.head`, assigning to `current` doesn't change `_list.head`.

Comment: I can't see any obvious errors. You should include the other functions: `append`, `prepend`, `updateDisplay` and the initializer to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Pointy Ok that makes sense, but then why do the (**) lines mutate the list if ```current``` is a local variable?

Comment: Because those lines don't change `current`, they change the properties of the objects `current` references.

Comment: It works fine, as expected, https://jsfiddle.net/kn1cpbz5/ what's the test case where it fails?

Comment: @barmar I looked more into that and it makes sense than assigning a variable to an object only stores a pointer to the object in memory. But then why do the (**) lines end up actually modifying _list?

Comment: Because they're assigning to properties, not variables. That's how you modify an object, by assigning to its properties.

Comment: If you know C, it's the difference between `ptr = foo` and `ptr->bar = foo`